# JPQL LEFT JOIN: is the collection member variable condition evaluated against all members?

Tags: jpa, jpql

Suppose I have a JPQL query like this:

```
SELECT p
  FROM Parent p
  LEFT OUTER JOIN p.children child
 WHERE p.children IS EMPTY
    OR child.x = 'y'
```

I would like `Parent` instances returned in any of the following cases:

- the `Parent` has no children
- the `Parent` has at least one child whose `x` is equal to `y`

According to the JPA specification, should the query above do what I want?  Or must I drag out the `EXISTS`-and-subquery-and-`IN` machinery?

Comment: Why don't you add some logging and find it out yourself?

Comment: Hello; thanks for your comment.  I'm interested in the spec-defined behavior, not implementation-specific behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your query will do what you want, no matter the JPA implementation. Personally I don't see any  room for doubt, although I can feel what you don't like: that the table `children` will be probably joined twice. But in my IMHO the JPA implementation should make two DB queries if needed in order to return the correct data.